# How to sort only certain rows within a group in pandas?

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe `df` that is grouped by `ID`. For each group, there is one row that has a flag that identifies that its the first instance `'First' == 1`.

I ultimately want to sort each group by admit date, however, I need the row with `'First' == 1` to be the first row of that group regardless of its date. Then I want to sort the remaining rows based on admit date.

Sample `df`:

```
ID     admit     discharge    discharge_location   first
20     3-4-2018  3-6-2018     Home                 1
20     2-2-2018  2-6-2018     Home                 0
20     2-5-2018  2-23-2018    Home                 0
30     1-2-2018  2-3-2018     Home                 0
30     1-15-2018 1-18-2018    Home                 1
30     1-20-2018 1-24-2018    Home                 0
```

expected `df`:

```
ID     admit     discharge    discharge_location   first
20     3-4-2018  3-6-2018     Home                 1
20     2-2-2018  2-6-2018     Home                 0
20     2-5-2018  2-23-2018    Home                 0
30     1-15-2018 1-18-2018    Home                 1
30     1-2-2018  2-3-2018     Home                 0
30     1-20-2018 1-24-2018    Home                 0
```

My approach does not account for the 'first' column being first within the group.

```
df.sort_values(by=['ID','admit'], inplace=True)
```

This has been stumping me all day.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

here it is bro,

```
df.sort_values(by=['ID', 'first', 'admit'], 
               ascending = [True, False, True],
               inplace = True)
```

Comment: Great answer, using the ascending parameter with a list of booleans for each sorting column. +1

Comment: coming from you I feel flattered :)

Comment: nice one noobie (-:

Comment: This isn't really sorting "only certain rows," it's prioritizing rows differently.